# How many orthogonal matrices(with a size of 3*3) are there, where all elements are whole numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I know of course what is an orthogonal matrix, $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I$, where I is the identical matrix. Should I maybe start with checking the properties of the orthogonal matrices?

Comment: Or I should maybe start with the fact, that the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is 1?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. If $Q = (q_{ij})$ is orthogonal, then due to $(Q^t Q)_{ii} = 1$, we have 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n q_{ij}^2 = 1 $$
for all $j$. Hence if all $q_{ij}$ are integers, at most one in each row/column is non-zero, namely $\pm 1$. So for each $i$, there is exactly one $j = \pi(i)$ such that $q_{i,\pi(i)} \in \{\pm 1\}$. Now, the permutation $\pi$ and the choice of the signs determines $Q$.